# echo is outputting "0" rather than the table

Tags: php, database

Look at code below:

```
<?php
    $output += "
    <table border='1'>
          <tr>
          <th>Session ID</th>
          <th>TeacherUsername</th>
          <th>Teacher Name</th>
          <th>Module Number</th>
          <th>Module Name</th>
          <th>Course ID</th>
          <th>Course Name</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Student Username</th>
          <th>Student Name</th>
          <th>Mark</th>
          <th>Grade</th>
          </tr>
    ";
           $total = 0;
            $count = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $count++;
              $total += $row['Mark'];
              $output += "
          <tr>
          <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['TeacherUsername']}</td>
          <td>{$row['TeacherForename']} {$row['TeacherSurname']}</td>
          <td>{$row['ModuleId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['ModuleName']}</td>
          <td>{$row['CourseId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['CourseName']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Year']}</td>
          <td>{$row['StudentUsername']}</td>
          <td>{$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Mark']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Grade']}</td>
          </tr>";
            }


              $output += "        </table>";

        $average = (int)($total/$count);
        echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";
    echo $output;
      ?>
```

For some strange reason it does not echo `$output` (which is at bottom of the code) properly. It is suppose to output the table but instead it echos `0`, why does it output `0`?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Don't use javascript's, plus but use php's dot

```
$output .=
```

But you have to also define `$output` first before using `.=`.

so in result:

```
<?php
    $output = "";
    $output .= "
    <table border='1'>
          <tr>
          <th>Session ID</th>
          <th>TeacherUsername</th>
          <th>Teacher Name</th>
          <th>Module Number</th>
          <th>Module Name</th>
          <th>Course ID</th>
          <th>Course Name</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Student Username</th>
          <th>Student Name</th>
          <th>Mark</th>
          <th>Grade</th>
          </tr>
    ";
           $total = 0;
            $count = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $count++;
              $total .= $row['Mark'];
              $output .= "
          <tr>
          <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['TeacherUsername']}</td>
          <td>{$row['TeacherForename']} {$row['TeacherSurname']}</td>
          <td>{$row['ModuleId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['ModuleName']}</td>
          <td>{$row['CourseId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['CourseName']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Year']}</td>
          <td>{$row['StudentUsername']}</td>
          <td>{$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Mark']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Grade']}</td>
          </tr>";
            }


              $output .= "        </table>";

        $average = (int)($total/$count);
        echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";
    echo $output;
      ?>
```

Comment: Your answer was the same as everybody else's. Fishing for check marks makes you look silly.

Comment: It worked but for some strange reason it says: Notice: Undefined variable: output in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/exam_grade_report.php on line 151. This is the line where it has "; at the end of the output variable. Why is it saying this?

Comment: @AlienWebguy: I had the only answer with OP's comment. I have deleted the comment I posted

Comment: @MayurPatel: define $output before using .= like shown `$output = "";`

Comment: I don't really care. It's not that important.

Comment: @Maruy  Could you untick my answer and accept AlienWebguy's one please? After all, he was the faster one

Answer (score 15):

You're concatenating JavaScript style. You want:

```
$output = '';
$output .= 'foobar';
```

Comment: It worked but for some strange reason it says: Notice: Undefined variable: output in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/exam_grade_report.php on line 151. This is the line where it has "; at the end of the output variable. Why is it saying this?

Comment: Cuz you're trying to concatenate a variable that hasn't been set yet. Either change the first one to `$output = 'foobar';` or else above all your code, set `$output = '';`

Answer (score 8):

`$output += " ..."` is  doing ADDITION, not concatentation. You're adding a string to a number, so PHP casts the string to a number as best it can, which probably comes out as `0`.

Try

```
$output .= "...";
```

instead. Or better, yet, use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc):

```
$output .= <<<EOL
...
EOL;
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `+=` will try to add 'value' of the string and not concatenate it in PHP.

Use `.=` instead.

Comment: It worked but for some strange reason it says: Notice: Undefined variable: output in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/exam_grade_report.php on line 151. This is the line where it has "; at the end of the output variable. Why is it saying this?